# How do I persist environment variables in Jenkins from a Windows batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, environment-variables

I need to persist some environment variables in Jenkins to a file that is later used to set environment variables on a Mac.  I assumed the following batch command contents would work just like it does in a cmd window:

```
set | find "PROCESSOR"
```

which from cmd.exe generates

```
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 44 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=2c02
```

when run from within Jenkins it produces the following

```
C:\jenkins\workspace\P_PIL\ManageEnvironment>set   | find "PROCESSOR" 
find: unable to access "PROCESSOR": The system cannot find the file specified. 
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

C:\jenkins\workspace\P_PIL\ManageEnvironment>exit 1
```

I'd rather stay away from POWERSHELL, but if that's the only way to do it, I suppose I can try.  I just don't understand the difference in behavior from the command line to a batch command within Jenkins.

Comment: Are you sure that the `find` being called in your Jenkins environment is the same one as you're using?  The path used by your user may be different than the one used by your Jenkins account.  Try changing your batch file to just echo out what the path is, and see if there is another `find` in a path that appears earlier than `C:\windows\system32`.  Alternately, just explicitly call `C:\windows\system32\find.exe`.

Comment: Ugh.  Thanks.  You are correct.  I was performing the operation from the command line as a different user from what Jenkins used.   The Jenkins user had some UNIX utilities on its path and was using a UNIX-style find.  I chose to use the findstr as suggested below to be disambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error I can tell find was actually trying to treat "PROCESS" as an file. I guess it is because the output of set didn't get piped correctly, which matches the following error messages. This is because the target pipe has been closed. I think it may relate to the behavior of find command. Try to use findstr instead.